# Is it ok to have one wordpress installation for server.com and www.server.com?

Tags: installation, customization, domain-mapping, dns

I am about to install Wordpress and I want to know if I have to redirect let's say url server.com to www.server.com if I want to have only one Wordpress installation.

I want users to be able to use both www.server.com and server.com It would be nice if the typed url won't change (from server.com to www.server.com) but it is not necessary.

Comment: WordPress does that redirection for you, if you have both the www and no-www going to the same site.

Comment: @Otto: so I don't have to do anything? Nothing what is suggested in both answers?

Comment: Yes, you probably don't have to do anything at all. I suggest trying it and seeing if its working properly before trying to fix a non-existent problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can do with your DNS / Domain Name Host.

You choose in WordPress (WP-Admin > Settings > General ) if you want to use `www.somename.com` or just `somename.com`

[image]

If you login in to your Domain Name Host (I use 123-reg) then look for *Manage DNS CNAME / A / TXT records*

You can see on this screen I have an `@` and `www` A Record which are both pointing to the same Destination IP Address.

[image]
The `@` and the `www` A records are your `www.somename.com` or just `somename.com`

Answer (score -1):

Great answer by Damien.

If you were using a theme like Thesis, and some other themes also have this capability, you would be able to choose easily between the canonical url of www.yourdomain.com or http://yourdomain.com on the theme options.

Comment: This is incorrect, the canonical URL is a function of the WordPress core, it has nothing to do with what theme you are running.